# Understanding the Angular--Asp.Net Core Stack

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Good day,

Please I do not mean to trivialize this forum. It has been of great help to me.

However, there are some basic questions that self-teaching students (like myself) need answers to. This would go along way in guiding us.

My chosen stack is Angular, ASP.NET Core Web API, EF Core (ORM) and SQL Server. I have found necessary online courses and projects specific to this stack.  However, do I need to learn the whole ASP.Net Core including MVC, Razor, Views, Viewbags etc to be proficient?

Comment: opinion based I am sorry

Answer (score 1):

No-one can really answer that question. Learning any new language is a personal thing and we all manage to do it slightly differently.

What was a great start thou, was to complete some on-line Pluralsight courses in Angular and C# APIs. I can especially recommend the Deborah Kurata Angular courses.

Most of these course step you through the process and build a working site. I have found this especially useful.

best of luck.

Comment: in fact this should be a comment